# run.google.script only if form is complete

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a form using the google scripts that will not allow submission unless all the fields are entered. Currently, I use the "onclick" command to run a google script that send the form data and files to my google drive. However, I only want the form to be submittable if certain fields are filled in (those marked required). If I remove the google.script.run command from the "onclick" portion of the submit button, then the form creates alerts/messages that say the user must fill in the required form. These messages do not appear when the google.script.run command is included. I haven't figured out a way to make it so that the google.script.run command only runs if all fields are completed.

```
<!-- Include the Google CSS package -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">

<!-- You can also include your own CSS styles -->
<style>
  form { margin: 40px auto; }
  input { display:inline-block; margin: 20px; }
</style>

<form id="myForm" name="myForm">

  <label for="myFirstName"> First Name *</label>
  <input type="text" name="myFirstName" placeholder="First name" style="width: 150px;" required>

  <fieldset>
  <legend> Personal Information </legend>
  <div class="inline form-group">
  </div>

  <div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="myLastName"> Last Name* </label>
  <input type="text" name="myLastName" placeholder="Last Name" style="width: 150px;" required>
  </div>

  <div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="myEmail"> Email* </label>
  <input type="email" name="myEmail" placeholder="" style="width: 150px;" required>
  </div>

  <div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="visa"> Check if you will require visa assistance. Otherwise, ignore. </label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="visa" value="Yes">
  </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
  <legend> Documents </legend>
  <div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="CV"> CV* </label>
  <input type="file" name="CV" required>
  </div>

  <div class="inline form-group">
  <label for="CoverLetter"> Cover Letter </label>
  <input type="file" name="CoverLetter">
  </div>
  </fieldset>
<p>  </p>
<input id="submitbutton" type="submit" style="margin-left:450px" value="Submit Application" 
       onclick="this.value='Submitting...';          
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
       return false;">
</form>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
  function fileUploaded(status) {
      document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
  }
</script>

<style>
 input { display:block; margin: 20px; }
</style>
```

The googlescript runs fine. I'm also aware of some similar questions about form validation. The google script specific ones do not use the same form format (they create the form in google script). I would like to make as minimal changes as possible to achieve the required functionality.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Current code for jquery:

```
 $('#submitbutton').on('click', function() {
    $(this).val("Validating...");
    //check for required fields
    var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       if ($(this).val().length === 0){
         $(this).addClass("warning")
         return true
       } else {
         return false
       }
   });

   if (emptyFields.length === 0) {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
    } else{
       $(this).val("Submit Application")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting before the messages can appear.  One way to handle this is to change your button to a button (instead of type submit), and then trigger an event on click.  Check for your validation, and if everything passes, submit your form.

example:

change your button to:

```
<input id="submitbutton" type="button" style="margin-left:450px" value="Submit Application" >
```

and the click event:

```
$('#submitbutton').on('click', function() {
   $(this).val("Validating...");
   //check for required fields
   var emptyFields = $('[required]').filter(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("warning");
       return $(this).val().length === 0;
   });

   if (emptyFields.length > 0) {
       emptyFields.addClass("warning");
    } else {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles(this.parentNode);
       $('#myForm').submit();
    }
});
```

and CSS

```
.warning {border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the built-in "required" validation instead of having to create my own validation function?

Comment: you'd need to move your google script to another page and submit the form to that page (so that the script runs AFTER the built-in form validation that happens on POST).  if the script can't be moved, an easy way to handle this validation is to check for empty required fields in jquery and add a class to empty fields (and add a red border using css tied to that class).  i'll update my answer with an example of this.

Comment: I'm having trouble passing the form to google script. "this.parentNode" was used previously because it referenced the form, but now it isn't working. I tried .uploadFiles($('#myForm')) and that didn't work either. The border also only shows up for the "upload file" section (though it prevents submission for all required fields).

Comment: try $(this).closest("form") for locating the form.  and you may need to iterate over  emptyFields when applying the warning class.

Comment: I got the form to properly submit, but still struggling with adding the .warning class to every required field. I'll attached my current code to my question.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: your other css is overriding the warning class styling.  change the css to: .warning {border: 1px solid red !important; }  JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6fo6o39L/

Comment: Awesome. Worked like a charm. Thanks!